# azkaban run selenium automatic python script flow failed when after execute about twenty miniutes,and the system becomes very slowly

Tags: python, azkaban

I run python script in azkaban.

```
enviroment:
CentOS 8.1 
azkaban 3.90.0
Python 3.6.8
ChromeDriver84.0.4147.30
```

In test.flow file

```
nodes:
  - name: job_test
    type: command
    config:
      command: python3 /home/azkaban/python_codes/pyib/activity/pickgoods.py
```

when after run execute this flow about twenty miniutes, the system becomes very slowly and the execution is failed.

```
28-07-2020 18:30:40 CST job_test INFO - Process with id 1403 completed unsuccessfully in 1727 seconds.
28-07-2020 18:30:40 CST job_test ERROR - Job run failed!
java.lang.RuntimeException: azkaban.jobExecutor.utils.process.ProcessFailureException: Process exited with code 1
    at azkaban.jobExecutor.ProcessJob.run(ProcessJob.java:312)
    at azkaban.execapp.JobRunner.runJob(JobRunner.java:830)
    at azkaban.execapp.JobRunner.doRun(JobRunner.java:607)
    at azkaban.execapp.JobRunner.run(JobRunner.java:568)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: azkaban.jobExecutor.utils.process.ProcessFailureException: Process exited with code 1
    at azkaban.jobExecutor.utils.process.AzkabanProcess.run(AzkabanProcess.java:125)
    at azkaban.jobExecutor.ProcessJob.run(ProcessJob.java:304)
    ... 8 more
28-07-2020 18:30:40 CST job_test ERROR - azkaban.jobExecutor.utils.process.ProcessFailureException: Process exited with code 1 cause: azkaban.jobExecutor.utils.process.ProcessFailureException: Process exited with code 1
28-07-2020 18:30:40 CST job_test INFO - Finishing job job_test at 1595932240480 with status FAILED
```

and azkaban-webserver.log under azkaban-web-server

```
2020/07/28 21:00:34.127 +0800  INFO [ExecutorManager] [AzkabanWebServer-QueueProcessor-Thread] [Azkaban] Successfully refreshed executor: iZbp1hb3esnbp3levrcg05Z:36037 (id: 16), active=true with executor info : ExecutorInfo{remainingMemoryPercent=45.705342424456234, remainingMemoryInMB=835, remainingFlowCapacity=30, numberOfAssignedFlows=0, lastDispatchedTime=1595936723440, cpuUsage=0.01}
2020/07/28 21:00:34.128 +0800 ERROR [ExecutorManager] [AzkabanWebServer-QueueProcessor-Thread] [Azkaban] Failed to update ExecutorInfo for executor : iZbp1hb3esnbp3levrcg05Z:44085 (id: 17), active=true
java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: org.apache.http.conn.HttpHostConnectException: Connect to iZbp1hb3esnbp3levrcg05Z:44085 [iZbp1hb3esnbp3levrcg05Z/172.16.184.105] failed: Connection refused (Connection refused)
```

anyone can help to resolve it?

Comment: Your job process crashes. There's probably some log output somewhere that shows you the Python traceback, etc.

Comment: @AKX , I'v add error log in question description.

Comment: No, I mean look at the job's error log: https://azkaban.readthedocs.io/en/latest/useAzkaban.html#job-logs

Comment: @AKX , thanks,according to your answer,I find the error log of my python code.

Comment: Glad I could help. I posted this as an answer you can accept.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your job process crashes. You can find its error log in the web UI for further debugging; see https://azkaban.readthedocs.io/en/latest/useAzkaban.html#job-logs